# product no found inapp purchase ios

Tags: xcode, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I tried a lot of solutions found in **StackOverflow**, but they don't help me.

I'm trying to get product's information with **product id**

```
func requestProductInfo() {
   if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {

     let productIdentifiers = NSSet(objects: "acces_all_tests_without_ads")
     let productRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers:productIdentifiers as! Set<String>)
     productRequest.delegate = self
     productRequest.start()
   }
   else {
     print("Cannot perform In App Purchases.")
   }
} 
func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
    if response.products.count != 0 {
        for product in response.products {
            productsArray.append(product )
        }
        tblProducts.reloadData()
    }
    else {
        print("There are no products.")
    }
    if response.invalidProductIdentifiers.count != 0 {
        print(response.invalidProductIdentifiers.description)
    }
 }
```

I always get "**There are no products**".

My **`product id = "access_all_tests_without_ads"`** is in iTunes Connect with a good application id, I already activate  **In-App Purchase Capabilities** at XCode.

[image]

I tried uninstalling the application from simulator/device but this doesn't work for me.

I created the product in **iTunes Connect** 32 hours ago.

I also enter all information bank contract tax ect, i do that 1 hour ago [image]...

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found Solution here:

[iOS in app purchase - no products received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947805/ios-in-app-purchase-no-products-received)

I create  a new profile for my application and it works like a charm now